# Cannot select an image inside a div in CSS to apply style to it

Tags: html, css

So I have an ID which is not working when I try to select it in CSS. It works fine when I leave the ID out and just write img{} but want to select that specific image so I do not have to apply it to all images. P.S. I am using Brackets.

```css
#contactmain img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id:"contactmain";>
    <img src="roses.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: It should be id="contactmain"

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error

```
<div id:"contactmain";>
```

Should be

```
<div id="contactmain">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<div id:"contactmain";>
```

to

```
<div id="contactmain">
```